# I'm new to python, and i am getting a error for the first if statement

Tags: python

shouldn't this code theoretically work, i am new to python coding and i am having a hard time working with this, I'm just doing some practices to get the hang of it. update thank you, i didnt pay attention, im going to leave it like this so if someone else missed a typo like that, they can see they were not the only one.

```
answer = input()
 
  if answer = 6:
    print("you are correct")
 else:
    print("try again")
```

Comment: do you want to do `answer == 6` (with double equals) for comparison?

Comment: [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: In programming you get 5 main different types (I know this is more complex and untrue but for simplicity).  Basically you're telling the computer if a variable you're saving (in your case 'answer') is basically going to be a string (str) which can be numbers and characters, or an Integer (purely numbers), or a float (decimal), or a Boolean (Bool), or a character (Char).  Look up booleans (True and False), (ASCII, UTF8 both used for strings and chars), these things may become a bit clearer.      (Arseniy is correct)

Answer (score 2):

1. The indentation is the part of syntax in python. You have an extra space before "if" statement
2. use "==" instead of "=" for comparisons
3. String to int

TLDR:

```
answer = int(input())
 
if answer == 6:
   print("you are correct")
else:
   print("try again")
```